# Writing numbers to the second line of txt file wtih adding number on it in Python

Tags: python

I have a script that writes the number at the end of request.url but I need to write it to first line of txt then I want to write another number to the second line of this txt by adding 50000 to the number

Here is my script:

```
f = open('numbers.txt', 'w')
            f.write(urlparse(request.url).path.split('/')[-1])
```

An example txt file that I want to make:

```
6100098 <<< this is written from request.url
6150098 <<< this must be written from adding 50000 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work if you need only those 2 number. Also I recommend you to add additional checks to make sure you got the correct value from the request.url.

```
with open('numbers.txt', 'w') as f:
    initial_value = urlparse(request.url).path.split('/')[-1]
    f.write(initial_value + '\n')
    f.write(str(int(initial_value) + 50000))
```